# MYSQL query to return count of rows of multiple user-input parameters

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I have a database setup to track bugs, with a profiles table to keep track of who's who, and a bugs table which contains the information on all of the bugs. The fields i'm interested in each table are:

profiles table:

```
userid | realname
---------------
1      | Bob
2      | Alice
4      | Carol
...
```

bugs table:

```
id | reporter | short_desc
-----------------------------
1  | 1        | short description 1
2  | 2        | short description 2
3  | 1        | short description 3
4  | 3        | another short description
```

where profiles.userid = bugs.reporter, and bugs.id is the id of the specific bug

I'm making an automated report creator in PHP that will eventually end up in Plotalot for Joomla, which means it has to be one query. The user of the automated report can specify what userid's of the people he wants to show up in the report. ie:

```
enter IDS: 1,4

reporter | bugs
--------------
Bob      | 2
Carol    | 1
```

The database has over 5,000 bugs and 400 active contributors. Is there any way to construct a query to return results formatted like that without using union select for each reporter?

Many Thanks

Comment: Are you talking about COUNT() and a left join? I can't figure out what UNION has to do with this :-?

Comment: UNION SELECT would have allowed me to construct a query based on every id in a for loop in php, ie
    SELECT realname, COUNT(*) FROM profiles INNER JOIN bugs ON profiles.userid = bugs.reporter WHERE reporter = 1 UNION SELECT .... WHERE reporter = 4;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick:

```
 select u.realname as Reporter, count(b.id) as Bugs
 from profiles u INNER JOIN bugs b ON u.userid = b.reporter 
 where u.userid IN (1,4)
 GROUP BY u.userid, u.realname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select realname as reporter, count(*) as bugs
from profiles p join bugs b on p.userid = b.reporter
group by realname
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
  u.realname as reporter
  Count(b.id) as bugs
FROM bugs b
INNER JOIN profiles u on u.userid = b.reporter
WHERE u.userid in (1,4)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT pr.realname, count(b.id)   
FROM profiles pr LEFT JOIN bugs b ON pr.userid = b.reporter   
GROUP BY pr.userid, pr.realname
WHERE pr.userid in (1,4 ) -- set your user ids here where report needs to be generated dynamically etc.
```